# pcl::io has no member savePolygonFile

Tags: visual-studio-2010, point-cloud-library, polygons, point-clouds, stl-format

I don't know where is the function savePolygonFileSTL in pcl 1.6. Which file do I have to include?

[Here](http://docs.pointclouds.org/1.6.0/group__io.html#ga9b899f282aaa92332e7a684c543e1a8e) it says that it is part of

```
#include <pcl/pcl_config.h>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
```

Anyway VS2010 doesn't find it, and also with manually search I didn't find the definition of that function in all pcl 1.6 folders. Neither savePolygonFile exists or similar.
How is it possible? There is something that I don't know? Please help me.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/writing_pcd.php#writing-pcd) tutorial, you could try to include the following include at the top of your code:

```
#include <pcl/io/pcd_io.h>
```

**Update**: by looking at the PCL 1.6 source code [here](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/pcl-1.6.0/io/include/pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h), it looks like the `savePolygonFileSTL` function is defined in the `vtk_lib_io.h` header. Try to include it adding this line to your code:

```
#include <pcl/io/vtk_lib_io.h>
```

Please be sure to have a VTK enabled PCL build.

Comment: I have already included it! It has no definition of that function. Where is its definition? How is it possible? Please help me

Comment: [Confirmation](http://www.pcl-users.org/Saving-PolygonMesh-as-STL-file-gives-strange-result-td4023803.html)